# postgres column with auto increment 12 digit int

Tags: postgresql, integer, schema

Is it possible to define a column that auto increments which is a 12 digit number on a schema level?

So the sequence would go `000000000000, 000000000001, ...`

Comment: `000000000001` is not a number, so you would have to do that as a string(varchar). Is that what you want?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that would be fine, but would the rule be enforcable as a varchar?

Comment: You can combine a `bigserial` with a check constraint. Then pad it with leading zeros on the application level.

Comment: @clamp is it possible to have it as varchar(12), maybe parse the column to integer and do a max select and increment it by one before insertion?

Comment: I guess the question is why the leading 0's are necessary?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver they are used for barcodes, which require a 12 figur nummer

Comment: What type of barcode?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver EAN-13, but the first digit is a constant, so I would not bother caring about it on the database if it compromises anything

Comment: For a compliant EAN-13 don't you only have 4-5 digits you can work with as the others are the prefix,  manufacturers code and check digit?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think that is only if you are using public EAN's. We are using a closed system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence specifying min,max,start values. Then assign that sequence as a default. You commented that your need is "EAN-13, but the first digit is a constant", from this I assume you actually need a 13 digit number beginning with a fixed digit. You can use that fixed digit as the leading value of the sequence. Something like ( assumes that constant first digit is 5):

```
create sequence barcode_seq
                 increment 1
                 minvalue  5000000000000
                 maxvalue  5999999999999
                 start     5000000000000;
```

While sequences tend to be used as table keys that is not a requirement. Use the above sequence as the default value wherever the barcode is assigned. [See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0db9292b8937a91d8f047344c4ee021).

Comment: If the answer was satisfactory and useful please accept it. Do not leave successfully answered questions open. Accepting answers helps later questioners that have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [the `serial` datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)? That's an auto-incrementing integer. It ranges from `1` to `2147483647`, which is a bit less than 12 digits. If you need something bigger, you can switch to `bigserial`, that goes up to `9223372036854775807`.

```
create table mytable (
    id serial,
    val text
);

insert into mytable (val) values ('foo'), ('bar');

select * from mytable;
```

```
id | val
-: | :--
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
```

Comment: it should be used for barcodes, which has to be exactly 12 digits. So sadly that is a requirement. Otherwise I would rather do a regular increment and append missing zeros in the application

Comment: @JonasGrønbek: if leading `0`s are significant, then you want a string, not an integer. You can generate it from the `serial` with an expression like `to_char(id, '000000000000')` - or do that in your application.